# making a list of ajax forms with struts 2

Tags: ajax, jquery, struts2

Trying to render a list, each of which has an ajax form to get further information.  The ajax call is being made, however, the results are not being placed in the target div.  Can anyone give me any tips or suggestions on this? Thanks.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Details</th>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="userList" status="itStatus">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <s:form id="detailsSubmitForm%{#itStatus.count}" action="users">
                    <s:hidden name="id"/>
                    <sj:a formIds="detailsSubmitForm%{#itStatus.count}"
                          targets="detailsDisplay"
                          button="true"
                          type="submit"
                          class="anchor-details"> Details
                    </sj:a>
                </s:form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
<div id="detailsDisplay"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this rendering as you expect? In other words, do you get multiple forms with the count rendered as part of the id?

In any case, rather than using multiple forms, I'd just generate `<sj:a>` tags with an id appended onto an "href" attribute. You don't really need to submit a form for this--you only need to pass an ID.

Comment: Yes, it does render correctly. The action is getting called, but the resultant content isn't being pushed into the target div.

Comment: Your Code looks good, can you see in Firebug if your AJAX Request is successfully?

Comment: Yes, the AJAX call is being performed.  I can confirm server-side that the results are calculated, but not being pushed into the div

Comment: @cnswann Is there anything in the JavaScript console?